# What is the smallest positive difference between two integers whose product is $2400$?

Tags: number-theory

> What is the smallest positive difference between two integers whose product is $2400$?

I just tried factorizing $2400 = 2*1200 = 4*600=8*300=\cdots$ and testing different pairs, but this is a slow and unreliable way of doing this question. What is the best way and fastest to do this question?

Comment: Fastest: $$2400=50\cdot48$$

Comment: Look for factors close to $\sqrt{2400}\approx 48.99$

Comment: Also: $2400=2401-1=49^2-1^2=(49+1)(49-1)$.

Answer (score 8):

Notice that $48^2<2400<49^2$. Manual trial gives us that $2400=50*48$. The intergers that divide $n$ with the smallest difference are the ones closest to $\sqrt {n}$. At least, this is nearly the quickest way when $n$ is composite.

Comment: "Generally, it is safe to say"... I'm not really sure why one can't always say it.  ... assuming n is positive ...

Comment: @fleablood I meant that that`s a difficult way if the natural number is prime. But it is still true for prime numbers so I have edited the answer.

Comment: Start with $\lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil$ and $\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$. If the product is too big, lower the smaller integer. If it is too small, raise the larger integer. Repeat until you get the right integer (which you always will, because eventually you will have $(1,n)$). Note that this could potentially take a lot of steps, especially in the prime case.

Comment: There are more efficient ways to get from $\sqrt{n}$ to the closet factor of n to $\sqrt{n}$ by considering the prime factorization of n.  But these methods are easier to simply do than describe.  2400 = 2^5\*3*5^2.  48 < root n < 49 and 48 is a root so we got lucky.  If you tried going up from 49 we want to look for the next multiple of 2 (50) or of 3 (52) or of 5 (5) and only if the have common factors.

Comment: If n is prime you know n and 1 are the only options.

Comment: If you had a "bad" number, say $2*13*25*17 =11050 $ then $\sqrt $ ~ 105.  You know one factor will be a multiple of 17 and 105/17 ~6 .. so 6*17 = 102. is near the square root but unfortunately 6 isn't a factor.  The closest we have is 5 so 5*17 = 85 and 2*13*5= 130.  ... kinda... you have to play with it.  The next higher multiple of 17 allowed is 10*17 and that too high and the next lower multiple of 13 allowed is 5*13 = 65 and that's too low so we can be pretty confident we found the closest middle ground.

Comment: It is true that you want the factors each side of $\sqrt n$.  Finding them may not be easy.  It is an example of the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), known to be NP-hard.  Just take the logs of the prime factors to turn it from multiplication (find the one just below $\sqrt n$) to addition (find the sum just below $\frac 12 \log n$)

Comment: This works well when the factors are near $\sqrt n$ (or the difference is small), but not that well when not. Try this for example with $n=2402$ instead. You would have to do a lot of trying before arriving at $n=2\cdot1201$ giving the difference of 1199.

Answer (score 1):

One of the fastest methodolical ways seem to be to use prime factorization of the number (finding them need you in worst case to test factors up to $\sqrt{2400}$ though):

$$2400 = 2^5\cdot3\cdot5^2$$

and then find the largest factor less than or equal to $\sqrt{2400}$ which turns out to be $48 = 2^4\cdot3$ and the other is therefore $2\cdot5^2=50$. This relies on the fact that the factors must be one that is at most $\sqrt{2400}$ and the other at least $\sqrt{2400}$. Using brute force means that you have to search through $36 = (1+5)(1+1)(1+2)$ combinations of $2^j3^k5^l$. But there are some tricks that would reduce the number of tries one is to use monotonicity and not check lower $j$s, $k$s or $l$s once you've found a combo less than $\sqrt{2400}$ or opposite for a combo larger than $\sqrt{2400}$. I similar trick is to find the closest of one of the exponents given the two others which reduce the number of combos to just $6 = (1+1)(1+2)$ (select $k$ and $l$ and deduce $j$ from that, but you'd have two candidates in general for $j$, one giving result below $\sqrt{2400}$ and one above, but one could quite easily deduce which one is nearest). A third trick is to notice that one of the factors must have the factor $3$ and searching for that includes only scanning through $j$s and $k$s and combined with the second trick that means that you only have to consider three cases ($l$ being $0$, $1$ or $2$):

$$2^j\cdot3\cdot5^0 = 2^j15 = \sqrt{2400}\rightarrow j=\log_2{\sqrt{2400}\over3}\approx 4.03$$
$$2^j\cdot3\cdot5^0 = 2^j15 = \sqrt{2400}\rightarrow j=\log_2{\sqrt{2400}\over15}\approx 1.71$$
$$2^j\cdot3\cdot5^0 = 2^j15 = \sqrt{2400}\rightarrow j=\log_2{\sqrt{2400}\over75}\approx -0.61$$

It's obvious which integer $j$ becomes nearest, so we get three candidates:

$$2^4\cdot3\cdot5^0 = 48$$
$$2^2\cdot3\cdot5^1 = 60$$
$$2^0\cdot3\cdot5^2 = 75$$

here we see that closest to $\sqrt{2400}$ is $48$ so one factor is $48$ and 
therefore the other is $50 = 2400/48$.

Another solution is to again use the fact that one factor is at most $\sqrt{2400}$ and then test with all alternatives less than or equal to $\sqrt{2400}$. In this case you would have to test $48$ candidates starting from $48$ and working downwards until you find a solution. In this case it terminates quickly as you find the solution at once.

The first method requires as mentioned to first prime factor the number which would in worst case require $\sqrt{2400}$ steps, but for each prime factor that is found the number of steps required to prime factor it would drop. The worst case scenario for that algorithm is if you're considering the product of two prime twins, for example $1763=41\cdot43$ where the second algorithm would win big time. On the other hand when you have small prime factors and still quite a difference the first method would be better, for example $2048=2^{11}$ would be prime factored in just eleven steps, and the solution would be found immediately as $2048 = 32\cdot64$ while the second method would need to try $45, 44, \cdots, 32$ (fourteen steps).